# Scalar Function Call

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a scalar valued function and it is complied successfully. But when i am trying to call that function it throwing error!! Check this sample code

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fn_lastupdate(@ID INT, 
                              @b  INT) 
returns DATETIME 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @lastupdate DATETIME 

      SELECT TOP 1 @lastupdate = lastupdate 
      FROM   clientlog 
      WHERE  id = @ID 

      RETURN @lastupdate 
  END
```

I am calling lyk

```
select fn_lastupdate(@id)
```

but am getting error as

```
 fn_lastupdate not recognized
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, you need to include the schema.  Try this:

```
select dbo.fn_lastupdate(@id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For scalar valued function you need to specify schema name(default: dbo) and need to pass all parameters.

Try this it will work

```
SELECT dbo.fn_lastupdate(1,2)
```